# Is there a way to get gnome-terminal on Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, macports, homebrew

Is there a port of gnome-terminal, or a way to compile it, or some other program that is typographically comparable, under Lion?

There is a typographic difference, and I can't duplicate it in Terminal; I can't even get Terminal to serve up anti-aliased text.

Comment: In Terminal, open its Preferences, check Antialias text in the Text tab of Settings.

Comment: Also, be sure to use a font in Terminal that can be anti-aliased. Alternatively, try [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/).

Comment: @lhf, Antialias is looking great.

Comment: @kccricket, iTerm2 looks very attractive, but on Terminal I have Lucida console 14pt, antialiasing, with a character spacing of 0.9 and a line spacing of 1.359. It looks a bit like some of the better typography on the web. I'm a bit puzzled why anti-aliasing is not default.

Comment: I would have to argue that the Mac OS terminal has MANY more customization options than the gnome one. You can pick all fonts, colours, AA, background colour, transparency, blur and so on.

Comment: You could make text lighter by changing the `AppleFontSmoothing` setting. See [More crisp font for iTerm on OS X - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/457253/more-crisp-font-for-iterm-on-osx/457352#457352).

Comment: Note that gnome-terminal most likely uses underlying fontrendering which means that the difference you see is caused by lower libraries or perhaps even baked into the operating system.  In other words I think you need to look elsewhere for the cause of your typographic differences.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install Gnome Terminal would be to use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/). Once MacPorts is installed, run `sudo port install gnome-terminal`.

[HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) is a newer alternative to MacPorts that is growing in popularity, but Gnome Terminal isn't available in the base repository yet.

Comment: MacPorts seems to be working and is pulling in hours' worth of goods to compile. Earlier I tried a port install and, to no one's surprise, MacPorts crashed.

Comment: I tried again and it took over an hour of compiling before crashing.